# New security layer on the library and environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have used my pipelines for over a year now and all of a sudden I have to review and permit newly added libraries and environments. This is not derisered as I add more and more libraries and environments over time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E2Zq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkdkV.png)

How can I remove the need to explicitly give these permissions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can put the pictures in the question instead of referencing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the pipeline, variable group, and environment permissions in the **Manage security** tab.
Link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-pipeline-permissions